# Big $O$ notation for limit evaluation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've seen a lot of tricky, or seemingly tricky limits absolutely nuked by the use of big $O$ notation on math se. Though, I've never quite understood how to apply these methods in practice.

Would someone familiar with the usage of big $O$ notation in limits care to elucidate its uses and strengths? Weaknesses too, if they exist.

It seems to me that often one can bypass a lot of messy algebra by simply using this sort of analysis, so I'd be happy to learn, and I'm sure others would appreciate a  thorough answer.

Comment: Your question appears to be too broad IMO. It is potentially as broad as asking "could someone teach me calculus?", I am afraid.

Comment: @String Surely someone could demonstrate the basics of the use of such a notation without covering anything too comprehensive.

Comment: everything that can be done with big oh can be done with limits. it is just a convenient notation. nothing more nothing less

Comment: There exists a [wonderful 1949 paper](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0037.03403) of [Francesco Tricomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_Tricomi) that would help you a lot, but it is unfortunately written in Italian.